# Trouble restoring from Amazon RDS DB Snapshot

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a few DB snapshots that I made on Amazon RDS from a couple years ago. I'm trying to restore those DB snapshots but when I select the snapshot and click "Restore from DB Snapshot" I get the error:

"Cannot find version 5.1.42 for mysql"

I first thought this was because I didn't have an instance running, so I went to DB Instances, Launched DB Instance, and created one of the same size as this snapshot. However, the oldest MySQL that is available is 5.1.45 so that's what I used. I was able to connect to it from my local machine and I confirmed it had no data within it.

Then I went back to my DB Snapshots and tried again and I still receive the same error even though I now have a DB instance running.

What do I need to do to restore this?

(I'm doing this all from the aws web UI)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an 'interesting' (and worrisome) problem - section *DB Engine Version Management* within chapter [MySQL Database Engine](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/RDSFAQ.MySQL.html) in the [Amazon RDS Technical FAQ](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/RDSFAQ.html) seems to imply that restoring an unsupported MySQL snapshot might not be possible anymore in fact (even though it is nowhere stated explicitly):

> **Does Amazon RDS provide guidelines for supporting new MySQL version releases and/or deprecating MySQL versions that are currently
>   supported?**
>
> [...]
>
> We intend to support major MySQL version releases, including MySQL
>   5.1, for 3 years after they are initially supported by Amazon RDS.
>
> **We intend to support minor MySQL version releases (e.g. MySQL 5.1.45)
>   for at least 1 year** after they are initially supported by Amazon RDS.
>
> After a MySQL major or minor version has been “deprecated”, **we expect
>   to provide a three month grace period for you to initiate an upgrade
>   to a supported version prior to an automatic upgrade being applied**
>   during your scheduled maintenance window.
>
> *[emphasis mine]*

According to [Impossible to create a RDS instance in EU-west](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=250048&#250048), MySQL 5.1.42 has been deprecated as of May 24, 2011 the latest already, so this *three month grace period* has long passed.

Obviously the apparent effect of this deprecation you encountered (i.e. the inability to restore respectively outdated snapshots) will come to a surprise for many, so there might be options to deal with it eventually still, but I'm afraid you'll need to contact AWS for a solution, either directly or via the [Amazon Relational Database Service Forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=60&start=0) - please post your findings as an answer here if possible, insofar I'd expect this problem to show up regularly as time goes by.

Comment: Wow, that's a huge disappointment. I'm running into this issue on a side project of mine which I have not had time to work on further since I posted this question. Hopefully I can get a weekend soon to dig into this further and I'll update here with what I figure out.